# How to transform a decision variable into a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, gurobi

I am writing an optimization model. I want to write the decision variable into Excel. The decision variable, that is binary, looks something like: x["a", "1a"]1, x["bb", "2b"] 1, x["ccc","2a"]1,...

Using the package pandas I already succeeded to write each decision variable into one cell. My code looks like this:

```
variable_x=[]

for var in m.getVars():
  if 'x'==str(var.VarName[0]) and var.X > 0.1:
    variable_x.append(var.VarName)

df= pd.DataFrame({'Zuordnung':variable_x})
book = load_workbook('Zuordnungsmodell_Datenoutput.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Zuordnungsmodell_Datenoutput.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Ergebnis')
writer.save()
```

However this will write the whole expression in one cell. But I rather want to have it in a way, looking like this:

A    B

a    1a

bb   2b

ccc  2a

I guess I need to transform the decision variable to a dictionary? Can anyone help me to do that? 
Much appreciated!!

Thank you 
Victoria